# Seperate Mipmap folders in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

While I've been messing up with my Android project in Android Studio, I had this "unneccesarily troubling" issue. On my main project (fig. 1) which I've been copying files from my test project (fig. 2) -for extra code safety- ; mipmap folders appear for every resolution seperately with resources in with corresponding resolution. 
But in my test project, which I've added these icons using "image asset" option instead of good old copy-pasting technique, these icons appear as icon folders with every resolution of them inside.

What causes this difference and how can I resolve it?

[image: Type One]

Fig 1: Main project with copy-pasted mipmap folder from test project.

[image: Type Two]

Fig 2: Test project including icons added with "right click on 'res' folder > new > image asset" option folder from test project.

Also, I'm open for grammatical improvements.

Comment: You have 'Android' as your view in Project, change it to 'Project'

Comment: You should not put other stuff than launcher icons in `mipmap` folders

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I'm interested, is there a reason for not putting anything else launcher icons in `mipmap` folders?

Comment: https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/14/goodbye-launcher-drawables-hello-mipmaps/

Comment: Thanks for the article.

I didn't notice selecting icon type as "launcher icons" will create an icon in "mipmap" folder whilst selecting "action bar and tab icons" and "notification icons" options will create an icon in "drawable folder" when adding new image asset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to switch to 'Project' instead of 'Android' view. (At the left top, above your project folders you will see 'Android' selected, so use 'Project').

Comment: Thank you, I've been so distracted that I did not remember changing views.
Sorry everybody else with this rather foolish question.

Comment: Glad I helped you. You can choose my answer as accepted if it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of view. Above that layout if you play around with the various options, you'll realise you can easily switch between these.

[image: Android Studio]

In the first case, you're most probably in "Project" mode. In the second case it might be that it's "Android".

Comment: Thanks for the image! I totally appreciate your help.